# read array from string php

Tags: php, arrays, string, filter

I have a string like this

```
$php_string = '$user["name"] = "Rahul";$user["age"] = 12;$person["name"] = "Jay";$person["age"] = 12;';
```

or like this

```
 $php_string = '$user = array("name"=>"Rahul","age"=>12);$person= array("name"=>"Jay","age"=>12);';
```

I need to get the array from the string ,

Expected result is

```
print_r($returned);

Array
(
    [name] => Rahul
    [age] => 12
)
```

**Please note that there may be other contents on the string including comments,other php codes etc**

Comment: Seems like a case for `eval()`, but only if you're sure this is the only way.

Comment: @Jack i do not want to execute the script ,

Comment: Anything you've tried so far?

Comment: Yes, eval is a way, but that could lead to security issues. How're you creating that string? IF we know that we might me able to suggest an alternate solution.

Comment: @xbonez like others suggested i tried to use `eval` , but it is a overkill , i tried to read the contents by line by line but the problem is that php have many formats for declaring arrays ..i was expecting a reg based one..which i dnt know anything ..

Comment: @Red Where does the string come from? Code in variables is typically just bad design.

Comment: @Red: if you have control of where the data is coming from, I recommend serializing it in a more standard format such as JSON or XML.

Comment: @Jack i know that ...also its something like a config options ,its strictly PRIVATE.

Comment: Without using `eval` it seems like the only way is to fully parse the code as PHP (which will be a very involved task). A regex is unlikely to be sufficient for this.

Comment: You could dump it in a file, and then include the file (this is essentially the same as doing an `eval` though)

Comment: @xbonez thats the problem i DO NOT want to execute the script ,even these arrays are not going to be executed ,i just want to display.

Comment: @saji89 its coming from admin configuration ,what i really need to be done is read content from a file and display its content on admin panel ,ex : $site["base_url"] = 'URL' ; so that i can make a front end for these config options.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on some magical regular expression, I would go a slightly easier route and use [`token_get_all()`](http://www.php.net/token_get_all) to tokenize the string and create a very basic parser that can create the necessary structures based on both array construction methods.

I don't think many people have rolled this themselves but it's likely the most stable solution.

Answer (score 1):

use a combination of `eval` and `preg_match_all` like so:

```
if(preg_match_all('/array\s*\(.*\)/U', $php_string, $arrays)){
    foreach($arrays as $array){
        $myArray = eval("return {$array};");
        print_r($myArray);
    }
}
```

That will work as long as your array doesn't contain `)` but can be modified further to handle that case

or as Jack suggests use `token_get_all()` like so:

```
$tokens = token_get_all($php_string);
if(is_array($tokens)){
    foreach($tokens as $token){
        if($token[0] != T_ARRAY)continue;
        $myArray = eval("return {$token[1]};");
        print_r($myArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: But i think that `eval` will execute the script ,there may be some other codes too ,  so a string based operation needed.

Comment: you can refine the regular expression above to allow `(` and `)` and it should work for you

Comment: Thanks for the start , i will try to modify the codes and will post a redefined one ,especially for PHP5'S new array methods.